# Window 10 wifi issue media disconnected

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, drivers, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Laptop Vostro 3555 with a Dell wireless 1701 802.11b/g/n network adapter made by Broadcom. The Device status: this device is working properly. This was a window 7 moved to a window 10. And I am not getting any X's of yellow signs in device manager.

Issue: The WiFi will not turn on. Will not show any access points to connect to.

What I have tried in order to fix the issue:

- 1. Download new driver from dell
  2. [Function key] + F2
  3. can not do ipconfig /release ../renew because it says `Media disconnected`
  4. Wireless properties > Power Management > UNCHECK allow computer to turn off device to save power
  5. Tried kb3084164 issue https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3084164

It might just me a bad card? What other steps can I perform to solve the issue before opening up the laptop.

Comment: This might be a long shot, but since you've tried downloading new drivers; try [upgrading your BIOS](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=N2KW4)

Comment: ok will give it a shot. will let you know tomorrow if it worked.

Comment: Your wireless is switched off. You probably need to install the Dell software tools and utilities to allow Fn+F2 to work.

Comment: Will try this today with the bios also.. thank you

Comment: OK installed the chipset driver and stuff started working.. thank for your help guys

Comment: Difficult problem to describe. Laptop was fine at first but then I suspect some updates caused this.