# Wi-Fi errors (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I'm currently troubleshooting a HP laptop (HP G62-a10SQ to be more specific). The problem is that it doesn't want to connect to any Wi-Fi network. It leaves me with the generic error "Can't connect to this network." I've tried these steps so far

- Restarting the computer
- Flushing DNS
- Releasing and renewing the ipconfig
- Uninstalling the driver
- Reinstalling the driver
- Reseating the Wi-FI module
- Checking Windows Update for any drivers
- Updating the driver in Device Manager
- Temporarily removing my Wi-Fi encryption
- Trying to connect to a different Wi-Fi network outside of my network
- Probably more troubleshooting steps I can't remember atm (I will edit the post if I remember anything)

Comment: What happened when you tried to connect to another network?

Comment: The same error occurred (Can't connect to this network)

Comment: 'key' is not a valid argument for this command.

Comment: try this netsh wlan connect name="Wifi Name"

Comment: Okay I manually added the network using the Networking Center, and when I try to connect using the `netsh wlan connect name=wifi_network` it says Connection request was completed successfully., but it doesnt connect

Comment: now try netsh wlan show profile name="Wifi Name" key=clear. If you are connected it will show your password

Comment: It shows the password, but I'm not connected (tested by trying to visit Google)

Comment: does ur ipconfig anything below Wireless LAN adapter?

Comment: Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Comment: See this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/995191/window-10-wifi-issue-media-disconnected)

Comment: Are you sure the networks you're connecting to don't have a MAC address filter in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, apparently I dumbed out and completely forgot that my network had a MAC filter (I probably didn't think about that because I had errors in the other network too, although I'm not sure why i got errors there). Thanks to @Daniel B for pointing that out for me. Thanks to @Codelt too for trying to help me :)